# Doing a 'ls' in a Docker Container on a volume mapped to the host hangs the command. (OSX)

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

Doing a 'ls' in a Docker Container on a volume mapped to the host hangs the command.

Steps to reproduce:

- Start up the container with docker-compose (see compose file below)
  The Container is a standard Postgres Image
- Enter the Container

```sh
docker exec -it mydb /bin/bash
```

- Do an 'ls' on the postgres_scripts directory

```sh
ls -la /root/postgres_scripts
```

And there it hangs.

CTRL-C breaks the command.

If I do a 'ls' on another directory, like /root, then it works. Even an ls on directories which are also a mapped volume like /export

### Resources and Versions

Docker Desktop version 4.3.2
Engine: 20.10.11
Compose: 1.29.2

Resources allocated to Docker:

- CPUs: 6
- Memory: 7 Gb
- Swap: 1.5 Gb
- Disk Image Size 60Gb (6Gb used)

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  mydb:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: mydb
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myusr
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
      PGPASSFILE: /root/.pgpass
    ports:
      - "8010:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      - ./deployment/user/.bashrc:/root/.bashrc:ro
      - ./deployment/user/.pgpass:/root/.pgpass:ro
      - ./export:/export:rw
      - ./deployment/postgres_scripts:/root/postgres_scripts:ro
    restart: "no"
    networks:
      my-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.0.201

networks:
  my-net:
    external: true
    name: cops-net
```

Why does the 'ls -la' command on /root/postgres_scripts hang?

Answer (score 3):

Found it!!

For some reason, OSX Docker Volumes have a problem with underscores in either the folder they are mapping or the directory (in the Container) they are mapping to.

I removed the underscore on the postgres_scripts name and it worked.

Comment: the same for dashes in folders in the path to the scripts.

Comment: Is there already a bug reported for this? How did you find out the problem?